# Tensorflow input pipeline - Queque

Tags: python, input, tensorflow

I have been working on a DNN project, which consists on an audio dereverberator (specifically speech dereverberation as described [here](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~dwang/papers/HWW.icassp14.pdf)). After some pre processing, my database ended being pairs of vectors which consist on the input/output for a supervised learning approach. My input layer consists of 3048 neurons, and my output layer of 514 neurons. The database is rather large (more or less 2 million pairs of input-output vectors). This led me try to implement a queque, because obviously I can't load the whole database in memory. I stored my files/vectors in CSV format with size = 3048, 2. The second column is filled with zeros after the 514th element (output layer). I have been trying restlessly to implement the queque as described in the input pipeline documentation and also following several tutorials. I found most of them incomplete, outdated or too brief for my understanding and purposes. I am a bit new to python also, which may slow things down for me. I have read many threads about it, and I know I am not alone, the input pipeline is confusing for many people, and I am happy to know that tf devs noticed this, so we should see some improvements in the near future. Meanwhile, if anyone can help with this part of the algorithm, I will be very thankful if anyone can point me in the right direction. I have no access to the code I have been trying to use, but if needed, I can post it later.